# Python beginner problems - Tkinter, Threading and bs4 module

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup

Running Python 3.6.5 with Anaconda, I'm not used to PEP yet, so sorry for my shitty code :P

I'm looking for a program which will check HTML code, where online players are and check if there are any Game Masters online. This code should be for players that are watching films while playing and are 'afk' in the game and bcs its not allowed to be 'afk' - this window should warn them. So I made code like this.(Ignore comments - I was trying to make it look better with pandas but its way too much)

What am i looking for?

I used a keyword 'ADMINS' bcs their guild is called ADMINS. 
Whenever GM appears in the online list - pop a window with some warning (GM is online!) BUT when I used threading, the code is running over and over and more and more windows appears. Is there a possibility to make that window appear just once and refresh it in given interval? Or to have a one window open all the time which will show '-' if there are no GMs online and 'GM ONLINE' if there are?

I'm using tkinter for the first time and I'm not really sure how to make it now. If u give me an example, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!!

```
import sys
import urllib
import bs4 as bs

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

gm = 'ADMINS'

def repeat():
    threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
    link = 'https://www.daemu.cz/zebricky/online/'
    request = urllib.request.Request(
        link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    #pocet_na_webpage = re.search('je online (.+?) ', str(source)).group(1)
    #df_table = pd.read_html(source)[0]
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    table = soup.table
    #filtering = df_table.filter(items=[0,1,3,6])
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        #print(row)
    if gm in row:
        root = Tk()
        label = ttk.Label(root, text="GM je ONLINE!")

        label.pack()

        root.mainloop()

    else:
        print('-')


repeat()

# prazdny_list = []
# for i in range(0,len(row)):
#     if row == gms:
#         prazdny_list.append(True)
#     else:
#         prazdny_list.append(False)
# row['sloupec'] = prazdny_list

# print(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your answer correctly you want that little Tkinter-window to either just show if something changed or to just change its text, right?
So for me, the way with less code would be the second one. Therefor I would start up that window in first place and just configure it by `label.config(text=<text>)`.

So to make it more clear for you - this should work:

```
import sys
import urllib
import bs4 as bs

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

gm = 'ADMINS'

root=Tk(className='Status')
label=ttk.Label(root,text='-')
label.pack()

def repeat():
    threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
    link = 'https://www.daemu.cz/zebricky/online/'
    request = urllib.request.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    #pocet_na_webpage = re.search('je online (.+?) ', str(source)).group(1)
    #df_table = pd.read_html(source)[0]
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    table = soup.table
    #filtering = df_table.filter(items=[0,1,3,6])
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        #print(row)
    if gm in row and label.cget('text')=='-':
        label.config(text='GM je ONLINE!')
    elif gm not in row and label.cget('text')=='GM je ONLINE!':
        label.config(text='-')


repeat()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I think I get your code, it looks good and I really like it, but I really dont know what should i put into that label.cget(text) area, cuz whenever i write some text into it, I'm getting an error. I'm sorry, I'm really a newbie in these things. Thank you!

Comment: @Leemosh I'm sorry. I missed the apostrophes around `text`. So it have to be `label.cget('text')` instead. My fault. What cget does is returning the value of the argument you want, so in this case 'text'. An advise from my side: Use effbot (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) to learn some more about tkinter if you are planing to work more with it in the future.

Comment: Hey! I actually tried that and it gave me error anyway. Not sure where the mistake was but I solved it in a different way. Maybe u can help me with another problem i got lmao. Gonna post the code.

Comment: and i was wondering about converting that into and .exe file or something that could work everywhere even without python installed. Bcs its really for ppl, for my friends,that doesn't code or anything and a simple exe file for win would be awesome. Do u have any ideas? :) Thank you!

Comment: @Leemosh Even thought you found a solution: Would you please send me the errormessage here? Cause I don't see anything wrong in my code. Thx c:

Comment: @Leemosh And according to your .exe-question: There are several ways to do that (py2exe, xc_Freeze, pyinstaller, ...). I would recommend pyinstaller - it's easy to use and works quite well, even with tkinter, matplotlib and so on. Here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4) is a very nice Video thats basically explaining how to use it. I don't think you'll need more.

Comment: Damn, I though it was some error msg but it appeared to be the errorcode after I closed the mini window. So there was no errorms at all.. It just wasnt working as I wanted.. :D Alrighty, Ill try to use pyinstaller. Thank you very much for that video and for help as well !!!

Comment: Ah ok, nice to know. ^^

Answer (score 2):

My problem here is, that sometimes the code works but sometimes it doesn't and i don't really know why. :D It gives me '-' all the time even if an account appears in the list of online ppl. Just change the gm variable to something different from the page. (for example: 'Teriyaki' or something else) Thanks anyway Nummer_42O, u really helped me a lot. :P

EDIT: I think I know where the problem is. Pasted the part of code. When I was checking the process, I found out, that this is only checking the last row. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import urllib
import bs4 as bs
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
gm =('ADMINS')
root = Tk(className='Status')
v = StringVar()
v.set('-')
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("red.TLabel", foreground = "red")
label = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=v, style = "red.TLabel")
label.pack()
#print(v.get())


def check():
    link = 'https://www.daemu.cz/zebricky/online/'
    request = urllib.request.Request(
        link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    #pocet_na_webpage = re.search('je online (.+?) ', str(source)).group(1)
    #df_table = pd.read_html(source)[0]
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    table = soup.table
    #filtering = df_table.filter(items=[0,1,3,6])
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        #print(row)
        if str(gm) in str(row) and v.get() == ('-'):
            v.set('GM je ONLINE!')
            break
        elif str(gm) not in str(row) and v.get() == ('GM je ONLINE!'):
            v.set('-')
        #print(v.get())


def repeat():
    thread = threading.Timer(10, repeat)
    try:
        check()
        thread.start()
        root.update()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        root.destroy()
        thread.cancel()
        pass
    pass

repeat()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to check each row by its own, put the if...elif-block into the for-loop. (But keep in mind that the for-loop is so fast that you may don't even see the changes. To avoid this import time and use time.sleep(1) or something.) If it's okay to check all rows at once just define row as an empty list (`row=[]`) before the loop and change the `=` after row in the loop to `+=`. Or more specific: Change `row = [i.text for i in td]` to `row += [i.text for i in td]`.

Comment: @Nummer_42O I actually solved that in a bit different way - u can see that in the code. Easily added break, cuz i didnt need whole table (that was just for me). So it is going to stop in the row where the kw "ADMINS" is.

Comment: I'm pleased you were able to solve it. Keep on programming and have fun. ^^